# onNewIntenet not in SherlockFragment so clicking on notification while on Fragment does not change the view

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, notifications, actionbarsherlock

I am in a difficulty now where I am not able to decide where to go to. I have a app where I receive XMPP packets in a service in background and from there either I make notification. Those notifications are made like this

```
     int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
     long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
     NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
     Notification notification = new Notification();
     notification.when = when;
     notification.icon = icon;
     Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
     notificationIntent.putExtra("title", from);
     notificationIntent.putExtra("message", message);
     notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
     PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
     notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, message  + " from " + from, "", intent);
     notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL; 
     notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND; 
     notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;        
     notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

As there are three fragments(SherlockFragments in MainActivity) so when the notification comes and app is in background. When I click on notification, it shows the values in Intent however, it does not show up the value if the app is in foreground and I click on the notification. Nothing seems to happen as onCreateView does not get called multiple times. How to handle that data so that I can see the data from the notification while on the app?

I am getting the data from Intenet in onCreateView like below

```
if(getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("title") != null)
    {   showMessage(getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("title"),getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("message"));
    }
```

**showMessage()**

```
public void showMessage(String title, String message)
{
    messages.add(title + ":");
    messages.add(message);
    // Add the incoming message to the list view
    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            //setListAdapter();//update the listview
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: can you post showMessage()

Comment: do you have override onNewIntent() in your MainActivity????

Comment: yeah I am posting the showMessage() and what would I do in onNewIntent in Activity, can I send data from MainActivity to fragment from there?

Comment: yes you need to override OnNewIntent method to get latest intent and in this method you can replace fragment again with new intent

Comment: @Hardik how can I use the attributes of Fragment class in MainActivity,

Could you please post some code to do it.Thanx in adavnce.

Comment: you will get new intent in OnNewIntent Method with data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    setIntent(intent);

    String title = getIntent().getIntExtra("title");
    String message = getIntent().getIntExtra("message");

   ///here replace fragment with data
   TestFragment testfrag=new TestFragment();
   Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
   bundle.putString("Title",title);
   bundle.putString("Message",message);
   testfrag.setArguments(bundle);
   getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.home_container,
                            testfrag)

}
```

Comment: bundle.putExtra or bundle.putString

Comment: keep in mind you have get that bundle in fragment using getArguments() method.

Comment: Thanx @hardik for the answer...

Can you help me out in one of my other problem?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25057531/sendbroadcast-does-not-get-called-in-activity-when-activity-is-opened