# sendBroadcast does not get called in Activity when Activity is opened

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, service, android-broadcast

I am making an app where I receive XMPP packets. My app starts in foreground and starts a Sticky Service if not started and start receive messages in backgrounds and make notifications of them. The notifications works well and when clicked they show the data. Issue comes (that too sometimes in some mobile phones) when I make a **sendBroadcast** call from service so that I can asynchronously update the text of message in Activity when it is opened.

My app is made with a Activity and within that there are two Fragments(SherlockFragment)

So I made a private broadcastreceiver in one of fragment where I want to show the text (updated text).

Code is written below

```
public class newMessage extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
@Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
   {    
    Log.v("ONMESSAGE", "broadcast");
       String action = intent.getAction();
       if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("NewMessage")){    
          Bundle extra = intent.getExtras();
          String username = extra.getString("from");
          String message = extra.getString("message");
          showMessage(username, message);
          Log.v("ONMESSAGE", "in broadcast is " + username);
         }
   }
}
```

I then make a statement of below in Fragment class

```
private newMessage messageReceiver = new newMessage();
```

in onCreateView I wrote the below line

```
getActivity().registerReceiver(messageReceiver, new IntentFilter("NewMessage"));
```

I did not unregister the broadcast receiver now and I tried doing that too.

When I receive a message in my service, I made call to below code.

```
 Intent i = new Intent("NewMessage");  
 i.putExtra("message", message);    
 i.putExtra("from", from);
 context.sendBroadcast(i);
```

I did not add the broadcats to to manifest cause I dont know how to do it when written inside a class.

Sometimes, it calls the sendbroadcase and everything works well however sometimes it does not call and just generate the notification.

Comment: first you try to add your receiver in manifest file add see what happen. from here you will get how to register receiver in manifest http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html

Comment: You said you added your broadcast receiver to a fragment. You should add it to your activity.

Comment: @Hardik How would I add the BroadcastReceiver to the manifest cause its inside a Class..how would I refer to it?

Comment: @Plinio.Santos..okay if I would have done that however, how to access the attributes of Fragment inside the surrounding MainActivity?

Comment: I am facing the same issue with broadcast receiver. The receiver is initialised inside the activity and even if activity is running the Broadcast is not received.